# I want to return a formatted Phone Number with use substring but odd thing return

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

I'm new to java. why this don't work ??
this must get something like this `formatPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])`
and after that return `(123) 456-7890`

Thanks for the answers.

```
public class Program {                                                                             
    public static String formatPhoneNumber(int[] nums) {                                               
        String nums2=nums.toString();
        String a_final ="";
        //"(123) 456-7890"
        a_final="\""+("+nums2.substring(0,2)+")"+"\t"+nums2.substring(3,5)+"-"+nums2.substring(6,9)+"\"";
        return a_final; 
                                                                                                 
    }
}
```

Comment: the step of array to string is not required...

Comment: `nums.toString()` Will not produce the output you expect it. See [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the toString(); method in a primitive type array the result is the location in the memory e.x "[I@1b28cdfa"

If you want to copy your array of numbers in a String just use the StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int number : nums){

        builder.append(number);

    }

    String nums2 = builder.toString();

    
    String a_final="("+nums2.substring(0,3)+")"+nums2.substring(3,6)+"-"+nums2.substring(6,9);


    System.out.println(a_final);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code produces the expected output (as posted in the question)? Looks to me like the last call to method `substring` has the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> `String nums2=nums.toString();`

doesn't do what you think it does. Check the result by printing it with `System.out.println`
A quick way to make it do what you think it does is
`String nums2=java.util.Arrays.toString(nums).replaceAll("\\D", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaskFormatter

```
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
//...
public static String formatPhoneNumber(int[] nums) throws ParseException {
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int value:nums){
        sb.append(value);
    }
    String phoneMask= "(###)-###-####";
    MaskFormatter maskFormatter= new MaskFormatter(phoneMask);
    maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
    return maskFormatter.valueToString(sb.toString()) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to convert an `int` array to a `String` using the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Program {
    public static String formatPhoneNumber(int[] nums) {
        String nums2 = Arrays.stream(nums)
                             .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                             .collect(Collectors.joining());
        String aFinal = String.format("\"(%s)\t%s-%s\"",
                                      nums2.substring(0, 3),
                                      nums2.substring(3, 6),
                                      nums2.substring(6));
        return aFinal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}));
    }
}
```

Since `final` cannot be used as a variable name, you changed it to `a_final`. I think you should try to adhere to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and hence I changed the variable name to `aFinal`. Using conventions makes it easier for other people to read and understand your code which helps when you want people to help you fix the problems in your code.

Also, the indexes you use in the calls to `substring` do not match your expected output (as posted in your question). In the above code, I corrected those also.

This is the output I get when I run the above code.

```
"(123)  456-7890"
```

Answer (score -1):

The `toString` method for an `int[]` returns:

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

Hence, you won't get all the numbers simply appended as string. To get the `nums2` string, you can just append the `nums` elements one by one as:

```java
String nums2 = "";
for (int e : nums)
    nums2 += e;
```

And the final result string would be:

```java
a_final="\""+"("+nums2.substring(0,3)+")"+"\t"+nums2.substring(3,6)+"-"+nums2.substring(6,9)+"\"";
```

Please note your `a_final` wasn't correct as it was missing some of the characters. I've modified it in the above.